# Is it safe to say that the dot operator is analogous to slashes in a file system?

Tags: java

For example, let's take the library java.util.Scanner

The Scanner class is located inside 'util' which in turn is located inside 'java'? So in a UNIX server let's say the Scanner is a photo located inside two directories. It would then be represented like this: java/util/Scanner.jpg?

So same concept but different delimiters? . and /

Comment: Yes I think that's correct.  You can look up how packages are handled in Java to get a better idea (like com.website.package) where it's kinda reversed.

Comment: Yes it does. But the dot is more specific (its a package delimiter and also an expression of where the package resides in the FS).

Comment: What is the reason that you're asking this? Yes obviously the dot separates parts of the package name in Java and a slash separates directories in a file system path. Just like spaces separate words in natural language and walls separate rooms in houses. That's all pretty obvious. They may be *analogous* in some way, but they're not the *same*. There is usually a reason why you want to get down to the specifics. There are also ways in which the dot in a package name is not the same as the slash in a file path.

Comment: The simple answer to this is no. It is not 'safe to say', it isn't an operator, the types of entities it separates are numerous and different from files and directories with significant and important contextual differences. You're more likely to confuse yourself deeply than gain any insight pursuing this 'analogy'.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt I wasn't asking simply if the respective characters merely separated each part. I was asking if the same concept applies relationship-wise meaning if it functions as a tree structure.

Comment: @Nico If that's what you're asking, then you should put that in your question, and then it can be answered (comments are not part of your question, so you should edit clarifications into your question). Short answer: no, packages - at least until Java 8 - do not function as a tree structure. It only looks that way, but packages are not hierarchical - there's only something special about classes in exactly the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Dot is not an operator, it's a separator: the package delimiter. Otherwise, yes it corresponds to the `/` (or `\`) in a filesystem.

Comment: In that case, yes, but it's an operator in different contexts.

Comment: Actually David, I don't think that the JLS calls "." an operator in *any* context.  For example, it is listed at the lexical level as a separator not an operator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.11

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two concepts are analogous at a very high level.  But a deeper level, the analogy breaks down.

For example, the "." symbol is used in Java in a variety of contexts spanning the class and instance hierarchies.  It means different things in each context.  By contrast the "/" pathname separator means (pretty much) one thing.

I would say that making this analogy is *NOT helpful* to understanding the Java programming language.